# How to implement GUI Less Oauth Authentication system to access API's built using Python-Flask

Tags: python-2.7, rest, oauth-2.0, flask-sqlalchemy, openid-connect

I have written a simple Python Flask API which does operations like adding data to Database and getting data from Database, there is no UI for this API, Now I want to implement OAuth authentication system for this simple API, As there is NO GUI,  I cant use google or FB Oauth Providers which redirects users to there login page.

In simple words, i want to create my own GUI less oauth Authentication system which secures my API as any user who wants to access my API should pass through this authentication system by passing access token in a header

I need Oauth Authentication system of my own for the API's below:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,make_response
from flask_login import login_user,logout_user,current_user,login_required,LoginManager,login_manager
from flask_oauth import OAuth
import json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_oauthlib.provider import OAuth1Provider

app = Flask(__name__)

class MYWIFI(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'MYWIFI'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column('data', db.Unicode)

    def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data


@app.route('/getall')
def getall():
    access_token = get_access_token()
    if access_token is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        languages = [u.__dict__ for u in db.session.query(MYWIFI).all()]
        for d in languages:
            del d['_sa_instance_state']
        print(languages)
        languagesJSON = json.dumps(languages)
        return languagesJSON


@app.route('/insert', methods=['GET','POST'])
def insert():
    access_token = get_access_token()
    if access_token is None:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            insert = request.get_json()
            id = insert['id']
            data = insert['data']
            print id
            print data
            new = MYWIFI(id, data)
            db.session.add(new)
            db.session.commit()
            return "Success"

def main():
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please can anyone help me in kick starting this

I appreciate for this help

Comment: There are [four different Oauth 2.0 flows](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use). If the client is the resource owner, then what you want is the Client Credentials flow. Do some research on it. This flow doesn't require any UI. Only when the client is acting on behalf of a user, you will need a UI for authorization.

Comment: Thanks Paul for  the response, I did get your point, i will look into it. Just for the clarification, i am putting up my code here , for this 2 API's i want Oauth authentication system:

Comment: @PaulSamsotha  I just looked at client credentials flow, i couldn't get it, Now you can see one INSERT API code , calling that API with parameters will add data to the database, now if you i mean PaulSamsotha wants to access data, you should be authenticated, otherwise you cant use the API.. This is the whole scenario

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is to build API endpoints which are protected by OAuth 2.0 tokens. If that's the case you as the API builder does not have to worry how token obtaining process happens. The client that consumes your APIs must perform the token obtaining and pass them to your end.

About sending in headers, try to stick with standards already exist in the OAuth 2 domain. [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) defines how to use tokens once a client obtains them. It defines bearer authentication schema to transmit access tokens. Check [section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1) to how header is set.

```
 GET /resource HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Bearer mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM
```

Where `mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM` is the access token. Once your API receives a request, from your end you must validate the access token before granting access. For this there is [RFC7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) which define the methodology to validate access token against the authorization server. See section [2 Introspection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2) to get an understanding of it. Alternatively, access token can come in a JWT format thus allowing it to be self contained.

Unfortunately, I do not have code for proposed solutions. They will considerable amount of codes. But I suggest you to separate authorization logic from your code. That means validation of authorization must be a separate module in your python code. But below I give a suggestion with my python knowledge.

```
@app.route('/insert', methods=['GET','POST'])
def insert():
    access_token = get_access_token()
    # Auth Validation for insert - This is based on access tokens
    # If token is invalid/not-present, exception is thrown with HTTP 401 - unauthorized
    my_auth_module.validate_access_token(access_token)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       insert = request.get_json()
       id = insert['id']
```

Also one final thing, your API should not worry about redirection for login. Let it be handled by your API client upon the 401 - Unathorized response.

Comment: Hi @Kavindu Dodanduwa, thanks for your response, But to verify the token, what is the reference for me, On what basis i should verify the token

Comment: @maruthirathnakar As I have explained in the answer, 1) you can use token introspection endpoint of the authorization server (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7662#section-2) 2) Else Access token could be a JWT, in that case your API endpoint can validate it for audience, expiration, issued time.